# My responsive website works properly only on some devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I created a responsive website but my home page is not responsive on any phone. I tried it on a few different ones.
[This is how it should look on phones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZUii.jpg)
[And this is how it looks on a few ones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbMfZ.jpg)

Here is the HTML of my homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssHomePage.css">
    <title>Catalin Sandu</title>
</head>
<body id="body">

    <div id="mydiv">
        <div id="topMenuName"><h1 id="name">CATALIN SANDU</h1></div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS for it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: gothic;
    src: url("Fonts/century gothic.ttf");
}

body {
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #595959;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: url("Images/background1.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="Images/background1.png", sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="background1.png", sizingMethod='scale')";
}

#mydiv {
    width: 30%;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.nav a:link, .nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.nav ul li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
}

.nav a:hover, .nav a:active, 
.nav .active a:link, .nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #5aada0;
}

#topMenuName {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#name {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 1100px) {

    #mydiv {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 770px) {

    #mydiv {
        width: 90%;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .nav {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

    .nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

    .nav a:link, .nav a:visited {
        width: 40%;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
}
```

I know that it is a lot of code right here but i have been trying to fix it for a few days and i can't find the problem. I also saw that it works mostly on iOS phones. Is it a problem in my code that android does not support?

Comment: You have overlapping media queries, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes i did it on purpose

Comment: What's the purpose of `(min-width: 150px)`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that when i try it on google chrome with the developer tools and I fix the phone size it works without problems.

Comment: Have you tried on different browsers on both iOS and Android?

Comment: Do not use the min-width for mobile. only max-width is fine.

Comment: I am still in the learning phase and i saw it in a video, the min-width. I tyied deleting it and it does not change anything

Comment: Yes I tried it on different browsers. On the android does not work at all

Comment: I saw that when I rotate my phone I can see more of the page's height. Is there any problem with the heights?

Comment: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the extra info, it looks like your `background-image` is set on `<body>`. This is all you need:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

---

Initial answer also contained this relevant part:

Another option is to use flexbox layout:

- give your `<body>` `display:flex; flex-direction: column;min-height:100vh`;
- set `flex-grow: 0;` on immediate children that you don't want to grow in height
- set `flex-grow: 1;` on immediate children that you want to grow in height.
  If you need a more detailed solution you should provide more details about your layout.

**Note:** Don't forget to prefix `flexbox`. Use [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) with this setting in `Filter` (down below): `>0%`.

Comment: But the background image is what appears to be the problem, and its height is not being targeted by media queries. The 'mydiv' div is probably fine, but can't be seen as the text is white.

Comment: Initially there was no indication on what element is having the `background-image`. Now he added info, it's on `<body>`.

Comment: I just tried it but the height of #myDiv becomes 100% of the page's height and I want it just like you can see it in the photo.

Comment: It is working now that i set the the display:flex; flex-direction: column;min-height:100vh;. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good luck and "La Mulți Ani" :))

Comment: Mersi mult de ajutor :)

Comment: La multi ani! :))

Comment: Te pot adauga la prieteni pe site-ul asta sau ceva de genu? Doar in caz ca mai am ceva probleme? Sunt doar la inceput si vad ca tu ai o reputatie destul de mare

Comment: Firstly, you should limit it to English on this website. Secondly, yes. See my profile > website > contact form. For everyone else, he asked me if there's a way to add me to friends on SO.

Comment: @CatalinSandu you should see the added note. You need it for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I can't find the contact form. Do you mean on your personal website? And what added note?

Comment: I added a note to the answer, you should read and apply it if you used flexbox layout. And yes, I meant personal website. The only way to send messages on SO is by opening a Room but that's overkill, imho.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the height of the page by targeting `html` and `body` like this:

```
html{
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 }
body{
 min-height:100%;
 }
```